# Parsing a string for same match multiple times

Tags: python, regex

I have  a String like.

```
1000 name1 x:<something1> y:<something2> z:<somthing3> 24 name2 x:<something4> y:<something5> z:<something6>
```

I want get the number at the Start, The name and the values after x, y, z.

I could come up was `[0-9]+ *[^0-9]+ x:(.*) y:(.*) z:(.*)` but it is not giving the correct results.

How to get the number, name and values and iterate them again and again for n line. It may also be like somethimes 'x:' itself may not be present what to do in cases like that. the number may not be present.

output I am looking at is

```
1000 name1 <something1> <something2> <something3>
24 name2 <something4> <something5> <something6>
```

Comment: Is your input on a single line as you showed? Or is it actually new line separated?

Comment: it is a single line.

Comment: Is there a number in the name as `name1`, `name2` as it doesn't seem to match your regex. `[^0-9]+`?

Comment: Yes there can be.  (.*?) (.*?) x:(.*?) y:(.*?) z:(.*?) I wrote like this. Just got to know about lazy and greedy. But this is matching the first part only leaving n parts. Crazy thing this regex.

Comment: Do you have space in all the five components or fields, if not maybe `\S*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(\d+)\s([^\s]+)\s(?:x:([^\s]+))?\s(?:y:([^\s]+))?\s(?:z:([^\s]+))?
```

- The matching groups for `x:`, `y:` and `z:` are optional (with an `?`). This means, the value of the group is just undefined, if it cannot match, but the whole expression still matches.
- Non-Matching groups `(?:)` are used to keep the numbering of the groups (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) clean.
- Spaces (i.e. whitespace in every form) were used to keep the groups apart. If a `<something>` contains a whitespace character, it won't work properly anymore.

*Here is an executable example in JavaScript:*

```js
var text = '1000 name1 x:<something1> y:<something2> z:<somthing3> 24 name2  y:<something5> z:<something6>';
var regex = /(\d+)\s([^\s]+)\s(?:x:([^\s]+))?\s(?:y:([^\s]+))?\s(?:z:([^\s]+))?/g;
var match = regex.exec(text);

while(match !== null) {
  console.log(match[1], match[2], match[3], match[4], match[5]);
  match = regex.exec(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line = "1000 name1 x:<something1> y:<something2> z:<somthing3> 24 name2 x:<something4> y:<something5> z:<something6>"

p1 = line.find (" ")
p2 = line[p1+1:].find (" ")
print (line[:p1])
print (line[p1+1:p1+p2])
values = [x.split(":") for x in line [p1+p2+2:].split(" ")]
print (values)
```

You don't need to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

To get all matches, you can use the following regex:

```
([0-9]+)? (\S+)(?: x:(\S+))?(?: y:(\S+))?(?: z:(\S+))?
```

So, in Python:

```
text = r'1000 name1 x:<something1> y:<something2> z:<somthing3> 24 name2 x:<something4> y:<something5> z:<something6>'
output = re.findall(r'([0-9]+) (\S+)(?: x:(\S+))?(?: y:(\S+))?(?: z:(\S+))?', text)
```

gives output:

```
[(1000, 'name1', '<something1>', '<something2>', '<somthing3>'),
 (24, 'name2', '<something4>', '<something5>', '<something6>')]
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the `<something>` are not in there. They need to be optional according to the questioner. And it is pretty similar to my previous answer.

Comment: Fixed by making the non-string part 0 or more

Comment: Not really, quote: `It may also be like somethimes 'x:' itself may not be present what to do in cases like that`. If `x:` is not there, it won't work.

Comment: Made x:  and the number optional

Comment: Then just turn it into a dictionary when you have parse the line number and name.

values = {x.split(":")[0]:x.split[":"](1] for x in line [p1+p2+2:].split(" ")}